# Visual Studio Team Services release issue

Tags: deployment, azure-devops

When I try to create a release within Visual Studio, I run into this error

[image]

azure deployment

Given that I have full permissions on my Azure account and I have no issues logging into my azure session

I think this is a bug within VSTS, the questions are, how to tweak this situation? can I use the Release management tool for visual studio 2013 temporary until I find out how to do a release

Rem: I tried the old method which uses powershell to get info about principal id, tenant id and so on but this method needs that my app has to be backed by AAD which is not the case for our situation and second this method is supposed deprecated for now

Any help will be highly appreciated

Thank you

Comment: What's the result of getting principal id, tenant id through that PowerShell script, then add Azure Resource Manager Service Endpoint?

Comment: The principal id is empty

Comment: Is the Subscription ID in "Azure RM Subscription" field entered by you manually?

Comment: @user2050269 Are there errors occurred?

Answer (score 1):

It is working fine for me. (Success configuring Azure service connection by clicking Authorize button).

You can clear Internet browser cache, then Start InPrivate Browsing, you can try it in other machine.

**》I tried the old method which uses powershell to get info about principal id, tenant id and so on but this method needs that my app has to be backed by AAD which is not the case for our situation**

You don’t need to configure app that backed by ADD manually, just need to run this PowerShell script directly (refer to [this](https://github.com/geeklearningio/gl-vsts-tasks-azure/wiki/How-to-Setup-an-Azure-Resource-Manager-Endpoint) article)

```
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage="Enter Azure Subscription name. You need to be Subscription Admin to execute the script")]
    [string] $subscriptionName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage="Provide a password for SPN application that you would create")]
    [string] $password,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage="Provide a SPN role assignment")]
    [string] $spnRole = "owner"
)

#Initialize
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$VerbosePreference = "SilentlyContinue"
$userName = $env:USERNAME
$newguid = [guid]::NewGuid()
$displayName = [String]::Format("VSO.{0}.{1}", $userName, $newguid)
$homePage = "http://" + $displayName
$identifierUri = $homePage


#Initialize subscription
$isAzureModulePresent = Get-Module -Name AzureRM* -ListAvailable
if ([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($isAzureModulePresent) -eq $true)
{
    Write-Output "Script requires AzureRM modules to be present. Obtain AzureRM from https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases. Please refer https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/DeployAzureResourceGroup/README.md for recommended AzureRM versions." -Verbose
    return
}

Import-Module -Name AzureRM.Profile
Write-Output "Provide your credentials to access Azure subscription $subscriptionName" -Verbose
Login-AzureRmAccount -SubscriptionName $subscriptionName
$azureSubscription = Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscriptionName
$connectionName = $azureSubscription.SubscriptionName
$tenantId = $azureSubscription.TenantId
$id = $azureSubscription.SubscriptionId


#Create a new AD Application
Write-Output "Creating a new Application in AAD (App URI - $identifierUri)" -Verbose
$azureAdApplication = New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName $displayName -HomePage $homePage -IdentifierUris $identifierUri -Password $password -Verbose
$appId = $azureAdApplication.ApplicationId
Write-Output "Azure AAD Application creation completed successfully (Application Id: $appId)" -Verbose


#Create new SPN
Write-Output "Creating a new SPN" -Verbose
$spn = New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $appId
$spnName = $spn.ServicePrincipalName
Write-Output "SPN creation completed successfully (SPN Name: $spnName)" -Verbose


#Assign role to SPN
Write-Output "Waiting for SPN creation to reflect in Directory before Role assignment"
Start-Sleep 20
Write-Output "Assigning role ($spnRole) to SPN App ($appId)" -Verbose
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName $spnRole -ServicePrincipalName $appId
Write-Output "SPN role assignment completed successfully" -Verbose


#Print the values
Write-Output "`nCopy and Paste below values for Service Connection" -Verbose
Write-Output "***************************************************************************"
Write-Output "Connection Name: $connectionName(SPN)"
Write-Output "Subscription Id: $id"
Write-Output "Subscription Name: $connectionName"
Write-Output "Service Principal Id: $appId"
Write-Output "Service Principal key: <Password that you typed in>"
Write-Output "Tenant Id: $tenantId"
Write-Output "***************************************************************************"
```

Comment: when i get a TenantId like this, the output is *******, is that just how it is shown in the log, or is it actually stored like that in my var?

Comment: @m1nkeh No, it should be actual value. Do you run it in windows powershell?

Comment: did $var.length, and it came back as 32, so i assume that it is just VSTS hiding the value from the log, i'll pass it in to my ARM template and see if it works! :D